# Android:How to save multiple checked checkbox state even closing and reopening the app

Tags: android

I'm using custom listview with checkbox...Whenever I selected checkbox items it's getting selected without any problem...After closing and reopening the app selected checkbox items are showing as unchecked....How to save the checked checkbox items after reopening the app....I know it is possible by using shared preferences...Here is the code

```
public class SelectUserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public List<SelectUser> _data;
private ArrayList<SelectUser> arraylist;
Context _c;
ViewHolder v;
//RoundImage roundedImage;
List<String> list;

public String blockedlist;

public SelectUserAdapter(List<SelectUser> selectUsers, Context context) {
    _data = selectUsers;
    _c = context;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(_data);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return _data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return _data.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}


@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.contacts_diplay_row, null);
        Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view1");
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view2");
    }

    v = new ViewHolder();

    v.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    v.check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
    v.phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.no);
    v.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pic);

    final SelectUser data = (SelectUser) _data.get(i);
    v.title.setText(data.getName());
   // v.check.setChecked(data.getCheckedBox());
    v.phone.setText(data.getPhone());

    final  SelectUser p = getProduct(i);
    v.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangeList);
    v.check.setTag(i);
    v.check.setChecked(p.isSelected);

    // Set image if exists
    try {

        if (data.getThumb() != null) {
            v.imageView.setImageBitmap(data.getThumb());
        } else {
            v.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
        // Seting round image
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(view.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher); // Load default image
        //roundedImage = new RoundImage(bm);
        //v.imageView.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        // Add default picture
        v.imageView.setImageDrawable(this._c.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e("Image Thumb", "--------------" + data.getThumb());

    // Set check box listener android
    v.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view;
            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                data.setCheckedBox(true);

                Log.i("cdcd", "onItemClick: " +data.toString());
              } else {
                data.setCheckedBox(false);
            }
        }
    });

    view.setTag(data);
    return view;
}





    // Filter Class
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    _data.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        _data.addAll(arraylist);
    } else {
        for (SelectUser wp : arraylist) {
            if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText)) {
                _data.add(wp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}




  // for check box................
    SelectUser getProduct(int position) {
    return ((SelectUser) getItem(position));
}

ArrayList<SelectUser> getBox() {
    ArrayList<SelectUser> box = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
    for (SelectUser p : arraylist) {
        if (p.isSelected)
            box.add(p);
    }
    return box;
}

CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangeList = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                 boolean isChecked) {



        getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).isSelected = isChecked;

        String result = "999";
        for (SelectUser pp : getBox()) {
            if (pp.isSelected){

                result += "," +pp.phone;// PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(pp.phone)
                list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add(result);

            }
        }
        blockedlist = String.valueOf(list);

        Toast.makeText(_c, String.valueOf(blockedlist), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
};

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView title, phone;
    CheckBox check;
}
```

}

Comment: Store the state of the checkbox in preferences and pull it out when you create your UI. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: You answered yourself in your question...use SharedPreferences.

Comment: `How to save the checked checkbox items after reopening the app` ??? Before closing the app?

Comment: Ya  I tried..By using shared preference I pass the checked checkbox value...While setting that sharedpreference value to v.check.setChecked(p.isSelected); some other checkbox also automatically getting selected while scrolling up and down

Answer (score 3):

Store the value of the check-box in the preference data, get the value from the preference whenever you open the app.

Comment: I had override OnResume method in main activity..And I got shared preference value inside that method...That also not working

Answer (score 0):

Take **boolean** value for each checkbox.